# How to Link Three Tables with CRUD in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm making a DBMS application where I would add a Donor, Donation, and MOA (Memorandum of Agreement) row entry. What I want to accomplish with this application is when I add those three rows using inputs from my frontend and press a button those three would automatically link up together.

Here is the ERD for the relationship. It's a classic many to many with a bridge type of relationship.

[image]

**The Code**

Donor.java

```
public class Donor extends Auditable implements Comparable<Donor>{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Cannot have an empty account number field.")
    private String accountNumber;
    private String accountName;
    private String donorName;
    private String companyTIN;
    private String companyAddress;
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
    private String address3;
    private String address4;
    private String address5;
    private String phone1;
    private String phone2;
    private String faxNumber;
    private String cellphoneNumber;
    private String emailAddress;
    private String salutation;
    private LocalDate birthDate;
    private String notes;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "donor")
    List<MOA> moaList = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
```

MOA.java

```
public class Donor extends Auditable implements Comparable<Donor>{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Cannot have an empty account number field.")
    private String accountNumber;
    private String accountName;
    private String donorName;
    private String companyTIN;
    private String companyAddress;
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
    private String address3;
    private String address4;
    private String address5;
    private String phone1;
    private String phone2;
    private String faxNumber;
    private String cellphoneNumber;
    private String emailAddress;
    private String salutation;
    private LocalDate birthDate;
    private String notes;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "donor")
    List<MOA> moaList = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
```

Donation.java

```
public class Donation extends Auditable implements Comparable<Donation> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NotBlank(message = "Cannot have an empty account number field.")
    private String accountNumber;
    private String accountName;
    private String orNumber;
    private String date;
    private Double amount;
    private String notes;
    private String needCertificate;
    private String purposeOfDonation;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "donation")
    List<MOA> moaList = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
```

What should I write on one of my services to have this feature of being able to sync the tables together?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```java
public class Donor extends Auditable implements Comparable<Donor>{
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "donor")
    List<MOA> moaList = new ArrayList<>();
```

```java
public class MOA {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    private Donor donot;

    @ManyToOne
    private Donation donation;
    ...
```

```java
public class Donation extends Auditable implements Comparable<Donation> {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "donation")
    List<MOA> moaList = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MOA {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    private Donor donor;

    @ManyToOne
    private Donation donation;

    //getters and setters

    public addDonor(Donor donor){
           this.setDonor(donor);
    }
    public addDonation(Donation donation){
           this.setDonation(donation);
    }
    
}
```

For linking up all the three entities

```
MOA moa = new MOA();
Donor donor = new Donor();
Donation donation =new Donation();
//enter the values for fields in donor, donation,moa class by using setter methods
moa.setDonor(donor);
moa.setDonation(donation);//by setting these values all three entities will be saved.
```